# Find a dynamical generated element by listening to a custom event (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, eventtrigger

I have a list whose `li` are generated dynamicaly via AJAX:

```
<ul>
  <li id="hello"></li>
  <li id="world"></li>
  <li id="helloWorld"></li>
</ul>
```

I also have a global var in my script like this:

```
var world = 'world';
```

I want, on document ready, as soon as the list gets loaded, to find the `li` item with the same id as my global var:

```
$('ul').find('#' + world);
```

I can't use a conventional `.on()` event listener here since there is no other event to trigger it, except for the end of the loading itself.

So my next step was to trigger a custom event in my loading script:

```
$('ul').trigger('loadingDone');
```

And then listen for it:

```
$('ul').one('loadingDone', theFunctionThatDoesTheSearch );
```

Problem is, this failed and it completely ignored any of the generated elements.

I know that a possible solution would be to run these operations inside the success method of the ajax call, but the current architecture of the app I'm building doesn't allow for that. (I can and do trigger the event inside the success AJAX method, I just cant do the search there)

Basically what I am asking for are alternative solutions for allowing the loading script to let me know when it is done and ways to filter trough the generated content without doing the filtering inside the loading script itself.

Comment: What ajax function does it use? You will *need* to trigger the event from the success function (or any other handler for the success event), why is that not possible?

Comment: I do that, but it still doens't work... its ok to trigger the event there, just not run the search inside.

Comment: Then please show us the code that does not work, you seem to use the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on("customevent","ul",function(){
console.log("event triggered from inside the ajax success handler");
});

$.ajax({
    url:'/echo/json/',
    success:function(){
    $('div').append("<ul><li>asd</li></ul>");
        $("ul").trigger("customevent");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xp7sr/2/

Comment: Yeah, this where I am stuck. I trigger the event, I successfully listen to it, but I still cant find the elements...

Comment: I fixed it, not entirely sure where the problem was, but I think it was something with the way I was listening for the event. When I set the document as the first parameter of the .on() listener and the ul as the second parameter it worked...

Answer (score 0):

If your ajax request is performed through jquery, you could try http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/.